# How to add number of observation to a box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure out how to add number of observation to my box plot .  The example in the package demonstrates how to add number of observation on box plot .but I need to write the number of observation on x axis  I'm going to make a reproducible example based on that.

```
# function for number of observations 
give.n <- function(x){
 return(c(y = median(x)*1.05, label = length(x))) 
# experiment with the multiplier to find the perfect position
}


# plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, label=rownames(mtcars))) +
 geom_boxplot(fill = "grey80", colour = "#3366FF") +
 stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a summary `data.frame` and pass it as the data argument to `geom_text` layer.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- count(mtcars, cyl)

# plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, label=rownames(mtcars))) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "grey80", colour = "#3366FF") +
  geom_text(data = df, aes(y = 0, label = n))
```

Comment: Thank you Imran, That was helpful